# Get and Set a Single Cookie with Node.js HTTP Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, httpserver

I want to be able to set a single cookie, and read that single cookie with each request made to the nodejs server instance. Can it be done in a few lines of code, without the need to pull in a third party lib?

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Just trying to take the above code directly from nodejs.org, and work a cookie into it.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

There is no quick function access to getting/setting cookies, so I came up with the following hack:

```
const http = require('http');

function parseCookies (request) {
    const list = {};
    const cookieHeader = request.headers?.cookie;
    if (!cookieHeader) return list;

    cookieHeader.split(`;`).forEach(function(cookie) {
        let [ name, ...rest] = cookie.split(`=`);
        name = name?.trim();
        if (!name) return;
        const value = rest.join(`=`).trim();
        if (!value) return;
        list[name] = decodeURIComponent(value);
    });

    return list;
}

const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    // To Read a Cookie
    const cookies = parseCookies(request);

    // To Write a Cookie
    response.writeHead(200, {
        "Set-Cookie": `mycookie=test`,
        "Content-Type": `text/plain`
    });

    response.end(`Hello World\n`);
}).listen(8124);

const {address, port} = server.address();
console.log(`Server running at http://${address}:${port}`);
```

This will store all cookies into the cookies object, and you need to set cookies when you write the head.

Comment: The above code will work incorrectly if the value of a cookie contains an equal (`=`) sign as in one of Facebook's cookies like `fbm_1234123412341234=base_domain=.domain.com`.

Comment: don't cookie values have to be URL encoded / percent encoded? = in the doockie value would be invalid in that case, right?

Comment: In that case split by `;` then by the first instance of `=`. Left is key, right is value.

Comment: I ran into the same issue as @Eye, instead of going the route of @iLoch I switched `parts[0]` to `parts.shift()` and `parts[1]` to `parts.join('=')`

Comment: The code given had serious bugs and people cuntinued to copy it. See my last update

Comment: @NicolasZ, no, unfortunately the issues noticed by Eye et. all are still there.  I found replacing `list[parts.shift().trim()] = decodeURI(parts.join('='));` with `list[parts[0].trim()] = decodeURI(parts.slice(1).join('='))` as per aron. duby's suggestion to work for me.

Comment: @user445786, the changes you mention don't actually change anything that I can see. The output should be identical.

Comment: Unless there is a question of which side of the equals sign get's evaluated first! In other words, does `parts.shift().trim()` really get evaluated before `parts.join('=')`?

Comment: The original problem mention by aron.duby is indeed fixed. And in Chrome dev tools, the left side is evaluated first. So everything should be good.

Comment: Cookie don't have to be URI encoded. The `cookie` npm library just does that by default (which is the express middleware `cookie-parser` depends on).

Comment: `parts.shift()` returns undefined if parts is an empty array. This will cause a type error.

Comment: I found 1 vulnerability. decodeURI throws an exception with improper URL encoding. (eg cookie header set to `test=%MKU` → CRASH)

Comment: That's not so much a vulnerability as it is expected behaviour, though: if you're parsing any user-side data (not just body content, but also headers, including cookies) always do so in a try/catch (whether you use this code or any other code).

Answer (score 130):

If you're using the express library, as many node.js developers do, there is an easier way. Check the Express.js documentation page for more information.

The parsing example above works but express gives you a nice function to take care of that:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
```

To set a cookie:

```
res.cookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
```

To clear the cookie:

```
res.clearCookie('cookiename');
```

Comment: The cookie library is actually from the underlying library connect; you don't need to take all of express to get cookie helper.

Comment: actually the cookie library is not part of connect (which can't set cookie)

Comment: `cookie-parser` is no longer part of express and/or connect, but is available as middleware: https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

Comment: How does one "get" a cookie in this example? For completeness and answering the question.

Comment: Agreed. I looked at the documentation and it is completely different now. It's hard to provide accurate advice on this topic now, sorry everyone.

Comment: Downvoting due to needing to install express just to use cookies

Comment: What if you only need to save cookies, but dont care about its content?

Answer (score 48):

RevNoah had the best answer with the suggestion of using Express's [cookie parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser). But, that answer is now 3 years old and is out of date.

Using [Express](http://expressjs.com/), you can read a cookie as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.get('/myapi', function(req, resp) {
   console.log(req.cookies['Your-Cookie-Name-Here']);
})
```

And update your `package.json` with the following, substituting the appropriate relatively latest versions.

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "4.12.3",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.0"
  },
```

More operations like setting and parsing cookies are described [here](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser)
and [here](http://expressjs.com/)

Comment: The question asks how to get __and__ set.  To set use this: `res.cookie('cookieName', cookieValue, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });`

Comment: Can you set and get cookies as a per-session (withouth the need to know and handle keys)?

Comment: Lot of express based answers to a question that shows code that uses the plain Node http module...

Answer (score 15):

As an enhancement to @Corey Hart's answer, I've rewritten the `parseCookies()` using:

- [RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) - use regex to parse "name=value" strings

Here's the working example:

```
let http = require('http');

function parseCookies(str) {
  let rx = /([^;=\s]*)=([^;]*)/g;
  let obj = { };
  for ( let m ; m = rx.exec(str) ; )
    obj[ m[1] ] = decodeURIComponent( m[2] );
  return obj;
}

function stringifyCookies(cookies) {
  return Object.entries( cookies )
    .map( ([k,v]) => k + '=' + encodeURIComponent(v) )
    .join( '; ');
}

http.createServer(function ( request, response ) {
  let cookies = parseCookies( request.headers.cookie );
  console.log( 'Input cookies: ', cookies );
  cookies.search = 'google';
  if ( cookies.counter )
    cookies.counter++;
  else
    cookies.counter = 1;
  console.log( 'Output cookies: ', cookies );
  response.writeHead( 200, {
    'Set-Cookie': stringifyCookies(cookies),
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  } );
  response.end('Hello World\n');
} ).listen(1234);
```

I also note that the OP uses the http module.
If the OP was using [restify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify), he can make use of [restify-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-cookies):

```
var CookieParser = require('restify-cookies');
var Restify = require('restify');
var server = Restify.createServer();
server.use(CookieParser.parse);
server.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  var cookies = req.cookies; // Gets read-only cookies from the request
  res.setCookie('my-new-cookie', 'Hi There'); // Adds a new cookie to the response
  res.send(JSON.stringify(cookies));
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: some suggestions now, 3.5 years later, for future viewers. Use `let/const` and `stringifyCookies` can be one lined with a `map` instead of building an array that way.

Answer (score 14):

Let me repeat this part of question that answers here are ignoring:

> Can it be done in a few lines of code, without the need to pull in a third party lib?

---

### Reading Cookies

Cookies are read from requests with the `Cookie` header. They only include a `name` and `value`. Because of the way paths work, multiple cookies of the same name can be sent. In NodeJS, all Cookies in as one string as they are sent in the `Cookie` header. You split them with `;`. Once you have a cookie, everything to the left of the equals (if present) is the `name`, and everything after is the `value`. Some browsers will accept a cookie with no equal sign and presume the name blank. Whitespaces do not count as part of the cookie. Values can also be wrapped in double quotes (`"`). Values can also contain `=`. For example, `formula=5+3=8` is a valid cookie.

```
/**
 * @param {string} [cookieString='']
 * @return {[string,string][]} String Tuple
 */
function getEntriesFromCookie(cookieString = '') {
  return cookieString.split(';').map((pair) => {
    const indexOfEquals = pair.indexOf('=');
    let name;
    let value;
    if (indexOfEquals === -1) {
      name = '';
      value = pair.trim();
    } else {
      name = pair.substr(0, indexOfEquals).trim();
      value = pair.substr(indexOfEquals + 1).trim();
    }
    const firstQuote = value.indexOf('"');
    const lastQuote = value.lastIndexOf('"');
    if (firstQuote !== -1 && lastQuote !== -1) {
      value = value.substring(firstQuote + 1, lastQuote);
    }
    return [name, value];
  });
}

const cookieEntries = getEntriesFromCookie(request.headers.Cookie); 
const object = Object.fromEntries(cookieEntries.slice().reverse());
```

If you're not expecting duplicated names, then you can convert to an object which makes things easier. Then you can access like `object.myCookieName` to get the value. If you are expecting duplicates, then you want to do iterate through `cookieEntries`. Browsers feed cookies in descending priority, so reversing ensures the highest priority cookie appears in the object. (The `.slice()` is to avoid mutation of the array.)

---

### Settings Cookies

"Writing" cookies is done by using the `Set-Cookie` header in your response. The `response.headers['Set-Cookie']` object is actually an array, so you'll be pushing to it. It accepts a string but has more values than just `name` and `value`. The hardest part is writing the string, but this can be done in one line.

```
/**
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {string} [options.name='']
 * @param {string} [options.value='']
 * @param {Date} [options.expires]
 * @param {number} [options.maxAge]
 * @param {string} [options.domain]
 * @param {string} [options.path]
 * @param {boolean} [options.secure]
 * @param {boolean} [options.httpOnly]
 * @param {'Strict'|'Lax'|'None'} [options.sameSite]
 * @return {string}
 */
function createSetCookie(options) {
  return (`${options.name || ''}=${options.value || ''}`)
    + (options.expires != null ? `; Expires=${options.expires.toUTCString()}` : '')
    + (options.maxAge != null ? `; Max-Age=${options.maxAge}` : '')
    + (options.domain != null ? `; Domain=${options.domain}` : '')
    + (options.path != null ? `; Path=${options.path}` : '')
    + (options.secure ? '; Secure' : '')
    + (options.httpOnly ? '; HttpOnly' : '')
    + (options.sameSite != null ? `; SameSite=${options.sameSite}` : '');
}

const newCookie = createSetCookie({
  name: 'cookieName',
  value: 'cookieValue',
  path:'/',
});
response.headers['Set-Cookie'].push(newCookie);
```

Remember you can set multiple cookies, because you can actually set multiple `Set-Cookie` headers in your request. That's why it's an array.

---

#### Note on external libraries:

If you decide to use the `express`, `cookie-parser`, or `cookie`, note they have defaults that are non-standard. Cookies parsed are always URI Decoded (percent-decoded). That means if you use a name or value that has any of the following characters: `` !#$%&'()*+/:<=>?@[]^`{|} `` they will be handled differently with those libraries. If you're setting cookies, they are encoded with `%{HEX}`. And if you're reading a cookie you have to decode them.

For example, while `email=name@domain.com` is a valid cookie, these libraries will encode it as `email=name%40domain.com`. Decoding can exhibit issues if you are using the `%` in your cookie. It'll get mangled. For example, your cookie that was: `secretagentlevel=50%007and50%006` becomes `secretagentlevel=507and506`. That's an edge case, but something to note if switching libraries.

Also, on these libraries, cookies are set with a default `path=/` which means they are sent on every url request to the host.

If you want to encode or decode these values yourself, you can use `encodeURIComponent` or `decodeURIComponent`, respectively.

---

References:

- [Cookie Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.2.1)
- [Set-Cookie Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1)

---

Additional information:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: If we're "clean" modern code, at least also turn that `createSetCookie` into a ```return [`${options.name ?? ``}=${options.value ?? ``}`, options.expires !== undefined && `Expires=${options.expires.toUTCString()}`, options.maxAge != undefined && Max-Age=${options.maxAge}`,...].filter(Boolean).join(`;`);``` (with the relevant indent of course). And note that an unspecified object property resolves to `undefined`, not to `null`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `!= null` checks for both `null` and `undefined` where as `!== undefined` will accept `null`. With your code, if `expires` is null, it'll crash when you call `options.expires.toUTCString()`. The JSDoc notation means you can pass null, with no issues. If not, the parameters would have to be `{!string|undefined}`. Also, there should be a space after semicolons, according to spec.

Comment: Single string is also faster than iterating arrays twice (`join` and `filter`), though our opinions may differ on legibility. The whole thing as a single String Template is probably even faster, but then I think it gets too unreadable.

Comment: Oh, wait, you used the coercive `!=`. That's kinda bad form, but sure, that does indeed do that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's not bad form. For example, `eslint` does not consider this bad. Most popular implementations use this, including NodeJS itself. There is no coercion because of how `==` works with `null` and `undefined`.  You're also not supposed to compare against `undefined` because that's the object in `globalThis` you're comparing against which can be overwritten (Try: `'undefined' in globalThis`). You're supposed to do `typeof object !== 'undefined' && object !== null`. But, using `!= null` is just cleaner.

See https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: good link, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "cookies" npm module, which has a comprehensive set of features.

Documentation and examples at:
https://github.com/jed/cookies

Comment: Looks like that module is intended for use in http servers. Is there a cookiejar tool for handling cookies in http clients?  Basically I aant to tell the http client lib: *if you get any Set-Cookie headers, remember them automatically, and then pass the on subsequent outbound requests as appropriate (when the domain matches).*

Comment: This would be a feature of your http client library of choice.
I can suggest [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent#persisting-an-agent-with-cookies-ie-sessions) as a good example.

Comment: Gave up trying to get this lib to work in express after couple of hours... use connect instead.

Answer (score 7):

To get a cookie splitter to work with cookies that have '=' in the cookie values:

```
var get_cookies = function(request) {
  var cookies = {};
  request.headers && request.headers.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(cookie) {
    var parts = cookie.match(/(.*?)=(.*)$/)
    cookies[ parts[1].trim() ] = (parts[2] || '').trim();
  });
  return cookies;
};
```

then to get an individual cookie:

```
get_cookies(request)['my_cookie']
```

Answer (score 6):

Cookies are transfered [through HTTP-Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
You'll only have to parse the request-headers and put response-headers.

Comment: Wikipedia not easier

Answer (score 2):

Here's a neat copy-n-paste patch for managing cookies in node. I'll do this in CoffeeScript, for the beauty.

```
http = require 'http'

http.IncomingMessage::getCookie = (name) ->
  cookies = {}
  this.headers.cookie && this.headers.cookie.split(';').forEach (cookie) ->
    parts = cookie.split '='
    cookies[parts[0].trim()] = (parts[1] || '').trim()
    return

  return cookies[name] || null

http.IncomingMessage::getCookies = ->
  cookies = {}
  this.headers.cookie && this.headers.cookie.split(';').forEach (cookie) ->
    parts = cookie.split '='
    cookies[parts[0].trim()] = (parts[1] || '').trim()
    return

  return cookies

http.OutgoingMessage::setCookie = (name, value, exdays, domain, path) ->
  cookies = this.getHeader 'Set-Cookie'
  if typeof cookies isnt 'object'
    cookies = []

  exdate = new Date()
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  cookieText = name+'='+value+';expires='+exdate.toUTCString()+';'
  if domain
    cookieText += 'domain='+domain+';'
  if path
    cookieText += 'path='+path+';'

  cookies.push cookieText
  this.setHeader 'Set-Cookie', cookies
  return
```

Now you'll be able to handle cookies just as you'd expect:

```
server = http.createServer (request, response) ->
  #get individually
  cookieValue = request.getCookie 'testCookie'
  console.log 'testCookie\'s value is '+cookieValue

  #get altogether
  allCookies = request.getCookies()
  console.log allCookies

  #set
  response.setCookie 'newCookie', 'cookieValue', 30

  response.end 'I luvs da cookies';
  return

server.listen 8080
```

Comment: Just copy paste that code in the TRY COFFESCRIPT tab on http://coffeescript.org/.
Your answer did help me, and coffeescript is not that hard to read if you know javascript.

Answer (score 2):

## Using Some ES5/6 Sorcery & RegEx Magic

Here is an option to read the cookies and turn them into an object of Key, Value pairs for client side, could also use it server side.

***Note***: If there is a `=` in the value, no worries. If there is an `=` in the key, trouble in paradise.

***More Notes***: Some may argue readability so break it down as you like.

***I Like Notes***: Adding an error handler (try catch) wouldn't hurt.

```
const iLikeCookies = () => {
    return Object.fromEntries(document.cookie.split('; ').map(v => v.split(/=(.+)/))); 
}

const main = () => {
    // Add Test Cookies
    document.cookie = `name=Cookie Monster;expires=false;domain=localhost`
    document.cookie = `likesCookies=yes=withARandomEquals;expires=false;domain=localhost`;

    // Show the Objects
    console.log(document.cookie)
    console.log('The Object:', iLikeCookies())

    // Get a value from key
    console.log(`Username: ${iLikeCookies().name}`)
    console.log(`Enjoys Cookies: ${iLikeCookies().likesCookies}`)
}
```

[image]

### What is going on?

`iLikeCookies()` will split the cookies by `;` (**space after `;`**):

```
["name=Cookie Monster", "likesCookies=yes=withARandomEquals"]
```

Then we map that array and split by first occurrence of `=` using [regex capturing parens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Capturing_parentheses):

`[["name", "Cookie Monster"], ["likesCookies", "yes=withARandomEquals"]]`

Then use our friend `Object.fromEntries to make this an object of key, val pairs.

Nooice.

Comment: Split with `/="?([^"]+)"?/` instead to support quoted values (eg: `name="value"`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookie lib to parse incoming multiple cookies, so that you won't have to worry about exceptions cases:

```js
var cookies = cookie.parse('foo=bar; equation=E%3Dmc%5E2');
// { foo: 'bar', equation: 'E=mc^2' }
```

To write a cookie you can do like this:

```js
response.writeHead(200, {
    "Set-Cookie": `mycookie=cookie`,
    "Content-Type": `text/plain`
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

#### Set Cookie

```
let key = "eyJhbGciOiJ...";
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `key=${key}; HttpOnly`);
```

#### Get Cookie

```
let val = request.headers.cookie.split("=")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cookie = 'your_cookie';
var cookie_value;
var i = request.headers.indexOf(cookie+'=');
if (i != -1) {
  var eq = i+cookie.length+1;
  var end = request.headers.indexOf(';', eq);
  cookie_value = request.headers.substring(eq, end == -1 ? undefined : end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what's in the `cookie` and you just want to use it, try this clean approach using [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) (a popular node module):

```
var request = require('request');
var j = request.jar();
var request = request.defaults({jar:j});
request('http://www.google.com', function () {
  request('http://images.google.com', function (error, response, body){
     // this request will will have the cookie which first request received
     // do stuff
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code makes no sense at all to me. Is `jar()` some cutesy method name to get the current list of cookies? What is the point of the 2 invocations of request? This is mostly an advertisement, not an answer.

Comment: Client answers are not accepted. Server answers are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simple function just pass
`req.headers.cookie` and **cookie name**

```
const getCookieByName =(cookies,name)=>{
    const arrOfCookies = cookies.split(' ')
    let yourCookie = null

    arrOfCookies.forEach(element => {
        if(element.includes(name)){
            yourCookie = element.replace(name+'=','')
        }
    });
    return yourCookie
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are many answer to this question already, but here's a function made in native JS.

```
function parseCookies(cookieHeader) {
    var cookies = {};
    cookieHeader
        .split(";")
        .map(str => str.replace("=", "\u0000")
        .split("\u0000"))
        .forEach(x => cookies[x[0]] = x[1]); 

    return cookies;
}
```

It starts by taking in the document.cookie string. Every key-value pair is separated by a semicolon (;). Therefore the first step is to divide the string up each key-value pair.

After that, the function replaces the first instance of "=" with a random character that isn't in the rest of the string, for this function I decided to use the NULL character (\u0000). The key-value pair can now be split into just two pieces. The two pieces can now be combined into JSON.

Answer (score -1):

First one needs to create cookie (I have wrapped token inside cookie as an example) and then set it in response.To use the cookie in following way install cookieParser

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```

The browser will have it saved in its 'Resource' tab and will be used for every request thereafter taking the initial URL as base

```
var token = student.generateToken('authentication');
        res.cookie('token', token, {
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9999999),
            httpOnly: false
        }).status(200).send();
```

To get cookie from a request on the server side is easy too.You have to extract the cookie from request by calling 'cookie' property of the request object.

```
var token = req.cookies.token; // Retrieving Token stored in cookies
```