# How do I share data across multiple browser tab or windows?

Tags: ajax, browser

I m currently building a facebook style notification system for my site.

I m using long polling. So, the server sends data if its available and closes the connection.

Now the problem i m facing is that, i want it to share across all open tabs or windows of that browser.

I m using a cookie to detect if a tab is already executing the ajax call, so other tabs will not execute it until the operation of the first tab is complete.

Now what i want is, to have an effective way, so that i can show the data across all open tabs in the form or a small fb style popup box.

The goal is if the last active ajax call has some data, then a small popup box will show up on all open browser tab or windows.

As, a theory i may be able to do it via cookie, but i want to know if there is some better way to do that.

Thanks,
Anjan

Comment: Browsers don't let pages talk to other pages.  You'd have to make an extension to get around the cookie.

Comment: So, i would have to settle for cookies? in HTML5 there is something like localStorage, i guess there is nothing similar in XHTML.

Comment: Yeah, HTML5 has a cache manifest type thing, but I wouldn't depend on it yet.  It isn't even a standard yet, much less supported by browsers.  AFAIK, it's only available on Chrome and Safari (maybe Opera, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Haha, yum.  I'll go ahead and create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don't let pages talk to other pages. You'd have to make an extension to get around the cookie.

If you're ok with the cookie idea, follow these examples:

- [For client side access](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)
- [For PHP access](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp)
- [For NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server)

Comment: You wouldn't need an extension to do this: there are other ways to [send messages between tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28230846/975097) on the client-side (using [postMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10885966/975097), for example).