# Get a cookie with nodejs

Tags: rest, node.js, cookies, jasperserver

I am doing a Rest call in nodejs to get a report from JasperSoft Server.
And
I need to get a cookie to stay connected but I don't know how to do get it

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8080,
  path: '/jasperserver/rest/login?j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin',
  method: 'POST'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {

  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);

  });
}).end();
```

So it work but then I want to have acces to another link like 
:localhost:8080/jasperserver/ressource/reports
And I need the cookie to do that. How can I do to get it  ?

For your informations,   console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
display the cookie and the path and some other thing, so maybe i just have to parse it and get the cookie from there but I don't know how to do.

Moreover, as I said I want to go to another link after being connected so can you also help me to set the cookie for another link ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get and Set a Single Cookie with Node.js HTTP Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server)

Comment: Good work Louis, this is along the lines of what I meant when I suggested that you run your Jasper server in parallel along the node application! I wish for your success. :-)

Comment: Thanks Linus ! maerics I tried that it just return and Object #{}Object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into using [Mikeal Rogers' request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request). It has built-in cookie handling, follows redirects, and other goodies. It's also a little simpler API than `http.request`. Your cookies should just work after logging in.

**Update:** Sample with `request` (`npm install request`):

```
var request = require("request");

request.post({url: "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest/login", qs: {j_username: "jasperadmin", j_password: "jasperadmin"}}, function(err, res, body) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    request.get("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/ressource/reports", function(err, res, body) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        console.log("Got a response!", res);
        console.log("Response body:", body);
    });
});
```