# Set a cookie value in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I'm developing a website with node.js and express. How can I set a cookie value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get and Set a Single Cookie with Node.js HTTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server)

Answer (score 43):

As Express is built on [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/), you can use the [`cookieParser` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieParser.html) and [`req.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.cookies) to read and [`res.cookie()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie) to write cookies:

```
// configuration
app.use(express.cookieParser());
// or  `express.cookieParser('secret')` for signed cookies

// routing
app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('bar', 'baz');
    // ...
});

app.get('/bar', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.cookies.bar);
});
```

---

[Update]

As of Express 4.0, [Connect will no longer be included with Express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#overview) and the default middleware [have been moved into their own packages](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware), including [`cookie-parser`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cookie-parser).

Comment: I have the same problem. When I replace app.use(express.cookieParser()); with app.use(require('connect').cookieParser()); There is Set-Cookie:currentId=b8RuviEVAytniu62; in Response Headers. But when I try to acces it with req.cookies.currentId i get undefined.

Comment: `cookie-parser` is not actually necessary for `res.cookie()`

Comment: `cookie-parser` is necessary for `req.cookies.bar` else express will not be able to parse cookies passed by the browser.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use the response object that express provides to set your cookies.

You can find detailed information on how to do that at: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie

Comment: THIS!! Exactly this! My colleague spent so much time searching for "express session write cookie" that they just did not bother to go through Express's docs.