# Express / node.js Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, response

I am trying to pipe my session api request through server in order to set an httpOnly cookie with session token, and ran into an error saying:

> Can't set headers after they are sent

Not entirely sure what this means, but here is my interceptor in express, that listens to a post to `/api/sessions` endpoint and in successful scenario sets a cookie

```
app.post('/api/sessions', (req, res) => {
  const url = `${config.API_HOST}/sessions`
  let apiCall = request.post(url, (err, response, body) => {
    if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
      const data = JSON.parse(body)
      let sessionCookie = { 
        path: '/', 
        hostOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true
      }
      res.cookie('SESS', data.token, sessionCookie)
    }
  })
  req.pipe(apiCall).pipe(res)
})
```

**EDIT**: reason why I pipe it is to be able and use promisses in my client side app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message above, you are are trying to send a response twice some where in your code. `Can't set headers after they are sent` implies that you code is trying to modify the response headers (probably in order to send a new response) after a previous response has been sent.

From your implementation, you are calling `res` in `res.cookie('SESS', data.token, sessionCookie)`in `apiCall` definition and also piping the `apiCall`  to `res` in on this line `req.pipe(apiCall).pipe(res)`, modifying the response object a second time. I think `res.cookie` calls `res.end` internally. If this is the case any further call or edit to `res` will throw the error you have.

You should be able to fix this by removing `.pipe(res)` part in `req.pipe(apiCall).pipe(res)`.and simply use

```
req.pipe(apiCall)
```

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240274/set-a-cookie-value-in-node-js) on how to set and send cookies in express and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent) on better explanation of the error message.