# Server side routes in Iron Router and Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, meteor, iron-router

### Forward

It seems that in Meteor, we cannot call a server side route to render a file to the page without some sort of work-around from our normal workflow, from what I've read about server side routes.  I hope I'm wrong about this, and there's a simple way to achieve what I'm looking to do...

** Sorry if this is a little long, but I think in this case providing more background and context is warranted **

### Software/Versions

I'm using the latest Iron Router 1.* and Meteor 1.* and to begin, I'm just using accounts-password.

### Background/Context

I have an onBeforeAction that simply redirects the user to either the welcome page or home page base upon if the user is logged in or not:

both/routes.js

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  if (!Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn())
    this.redirect('welcome.view');
  else
    this.next();
  }
  ,{except: 'welcome.view'}
);

Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  if (Meteor.user())
    this.redirect('home.view');
  else
    this.next();
  }
  ,{only: 'welcome.view'}
);
```

In the same file, both/routes.js, I have a simple server side route that renders a pdf to the screen, and if I remove the onBeforeAction code, the route works (the pdf renders to the page):

```
Router.route('/pdf-server', function() {
  var filePath = process.env.PWD + "/server/.files/users/test.pdf";
  console.log(filePath);
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  this.response.write(data);
  this.response.end();
}, {where: 'server'});
```

### Exception thrown on Server Route

It's beside the point, but I get an exception when I add the above server side route to the file and take the route /pdf-server, while keeping the onBeforeAction code in place.

Insights into the exception can be found here: [SO Question on Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693247/exception-when-using-a-server-route-and-onbeforeaction)

### Solution to the Exception

The main gist of the answer in the SO Question above is `"You use Meteor.user() in your Route.onBeforeAction but it has no access to this information"`, and when, `"your browser make a GET/POST request"` [Server side route?], `"to the server it doesn't have any  information regarding the user's authentication state."`

The solution, according to the same SO answerer is to `"find an alternative way to authenticate the user,"` and one way to do this is to use `"cookies'"`.

So, following up on this, I found another SO answer (by the same answerer as before), where a method to set and get the cookies is outlined here: [SO Cookies technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727922/access-meteor-userid-from-outside-a-method-publish)

** So, to summarize, in order to allow for server side routes, it is suggested I use cookies instead of something like Meteor.userId() or this.userId. **

### Cookie related code added

So I added the following code to my project:
client/main.js

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    if(Accounts.loginServicesConfigured() && Meteor.userId()) {
        setCookie("meteor_userid",Meteor.userId(),30);
        setCookie("meteor_logintoken",localStorage.getItem("Meteor.loginToken"),30);
    }
});
```

In my server side route, I changed the route to this:

both/routes.js

```
Router.route('/pdf-server', function() {
  //Parse cookies using get_cookies function from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server
  var userId = get_cookies(req)['meteor_usserid'];
  var loginToken = get_cookies(req)['meteor_logintoken'];
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId, "services.resume.loginTokens.token":loginToken});
  var loggedInUser = (user)?user.username : "Not logged in";

  var filePath = process.env.PWD + "/server/.files/users/test.pdf";
  console.log(filePath);
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  this.response.write(data);
  this.response.end();
}, {where: 'server'});
```

But this does not work as expected, the setCookie code is not valid for some reason.

### My Questions

> Question 1: Setting/getting the cookies in the manner depicted in the
>   [SO Cookies technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727922/access-meteor-userid-from-outside-a-method-publish) doesn't seem to work for me, does this
>   technique still work in '15?
>
> Question 2: Using cookies, how do I inform the server of the
>   authentication state based on these cookies?  Or, another way, How does adding the cookie check in my server
>   side route "inform" the server about the user?  I could check for
>   anything in this route really; I could reject any user, but somehow
>   the server needs to "know" about the user logged in right?
>
> Question 3: Is cookies the best way to go about this, or is there a
>   simpler way to achieve the same thing?
>
> Side Question: I've seen a few places where middle ware is used for
>   server side routes, for example:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(...);

WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(...) ...);
```

> But none of these examples had security inside, will using middle ware
>   in this way allow me to get around my problem?

Comment: Meteor doesn't include cookie support by default because cookies enable a large number of attack vectors, e.g. [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). Unfortunately, server-side routes don't have access to authentication information so you are left with devising a system which you feel sufficiently proves that the user is who they say they are. This usually takes the form of some kind of token or key. That key *could* be stored in a cookie, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: In your particular use case, does the `pdf-server` route need to know which user is making the request, or is any authenticated user sufficient?

Comment: David, no, that's one of the parts that I really don't fully understand.  I haven't told the server it needs to authenticate the user for that route.  Somehow, onBeforeAction is the code throwing the error when I take the pdf-server route.  So I suppose, when the Server side route is taken, onBeforeAction is called first, and tries to check for Meteor.user(), and since it's a Server side route, there is no Meteor.user(), so it throws.  On the client side, with onBeforeAction, the routes are fine because Meteor.user() exists there.

Comment: So, I'm guessing I should set the cookies (the cookie code above doesn't work right now) and check for that in onBeforeAction instead of Meteor.user()...

Comment: Oh, I see the source of the confusion now. I'll add an answer but we may need to iterate on it together to get something working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your server-side routes are running the global `onBeforeAction` code (it's defined in a shared directory), which breaks because the server routes are simple REST endpoints which don't understand user authentication information (i.e. `Meteor.user()` doesn't work). The solution is to wrap the client-specific `onBeforeAction` calls with `Meteor.isClient` or simply move that code under the `client` directory. For example:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    if (!Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn())
      this.redirect('welcome.view');
    else
      this.next();
    }
    ,{except: 'welcome.view'}
  );

  Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    if (Meteor.user())
      this.redirect('home.view');
    else
      this.next();
    }
    ,{only: 'welcome.view'}
  );
}

Router.route('/pdf-server', function() {
  ...
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Comment: Great, this works! Now all that's left is to make sure the user accessing the file is actually authenticated right?

Comment: I guess I should add another SO Question for the narrow question on authentication for the server side route?  Like a cookie or a technique from the API Security - Best Practices section here: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API?

Comment: Awesome! Okay, we solved the first part so maybe accept this answer and open a new one. The new question shouldn't give all of the background - just simply ask for the best way to authenticate a user in a server-side route. I'd just delete your other two open questions as they are less relevant now.

Comment: The SO Question on server side route authentication is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734110/authentication-on-server-side-routes-in-meteor