# Meteor middleware and Server side routes

Tags: node.js, meteor, routes, iron-router, middleware

It seems that in Meteor, we cannot call a server side route to render a file to the page without some sort of work-around from our normal workflow, from what I've read about server side routes.  I hope I'm wrong about this, and there's a simple way to achieve what I'm looking to do...

### Software/Versions

I'm using the latest Iron Router 1.* and Meteor 1.* and to begin, I'm just using accounts-password.

### Background/Context

I have an onBeforeAction that simply redirects the user to either the welcome page or home page base upon if the user is logged in or not:

both/routes.js

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  if (!Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn())
    this.redirect('welcome.view');
  else
    this.next();
  }
  ,{except: 'welcome.view'}
);

Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  if (Meteor.user())
    this.redirect('home.view');
  else
    this.next();
  }
  ,{only: 'welcome.view'}
);
```

In the same file, both/routes.js, I have a simple server side route that renders a pdf to the screen, and if I remove the onBeforeAction code, the route works (the pdf renders to the page):

```
Router.route('/pdf-server', function() {
  var filePath = process.env.PWD + "/server/.files/users/test.pdf";
  console.log(filePath);
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  this.response.write(data);
  this.response.end();
}, {where: 'server'});
```

### Exception thrown on Server Route

It's beside the point, but I get an exception when I add the above server side route to the file and take the route /pdf-server, while keeping the onBeforeAction code in place.

Insights into the exception can be found here: [SO Question on Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693247/exception-when-using-a-server-route-and-onbeforeaction)

### My Question

> Question 4: I've seen a few places where middle ware is used for
>   server side routes, for example:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(...);

WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(...) ...);
```

> But none of these examples had security inside, will using middle ware
>   in this way allow me to get around my problem?

Note: this question is a subset of a larger SO question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714618/server-side-routes-in-iron-router-and-meteor), but I thought I'd break this out as the topic really deserves its own question IMO.

Comment: No, it's a lower-level API but it doesn't solve the problem that server routes are essentially simple REST endpoints that don't know if the requesting client is a connected user or not. Some suggestions can be found [here](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API) - specifically in the **API Security** section.

Comment: David, thanks for the reference.  I'll read it, but my first thought is: I'm using onBeforeAction for my client side routes, so how do I bypass onBeforeAction for the server side routes so I don't get an exception when onBeforeAction fires first and tries to reference Meteor.user()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David Weldon answered the part of the question, how to render the server side route: [Server side routes in Iron Router and Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714618/server-side-routes-in-iron-router-and-meteor).   Middleware doesn't solve the other half, which is authentication.  A SO question has been posted about that here: [Authentication on Server side routes in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734110/authentication-on-server-side-routes-in-meteor)