# Set cookie and redirect, without express

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, cookies

I want to be able to set a cookie and then redirect the client with `node.js`, without using `Express` or another third party library. Online I can only find examples using `Express`.

When I try to set the cookie and redirect the client, the cookie does not get set. But when I comment out the redirect, `res.writeHead(301, {Location: serverAddress});`, the cookie gets set, but there is no redirect.

So how do I set a cookie and then redirect the client using straight `node.js`?

```
var fs = require("fs");
var http = require('http');

var home = fs.readFileSync('random.html');

var serverAddress = "http://yourIpAddress";

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if(req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'});
    res.end();

  } else if(req.headers.cookie) {

    console.log("Got cookie");

    res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(home);
    res.end();

  } else {

    console.log('Creating Cookie');

    var cookie = {
      "some": "data"
    };

    res.writeHead(200, {'Set-Cookie': cookie, 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    res.writeHead(301, {Location: serverAddress});

    res.end();

  }
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: is there a reason why you can't use express?

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't you have to do `"set-Cookie" : "some=data; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT"` etc instead of passing in an object, and are you sure `req.headers.cookie` gets populated without a cookieparser middleware. My opinion is that you're reinventing the wheel and should use available middleware.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server

Comment: @Daemedeor I saw that link and that only solves getting and setting cookies, not redirecting after.

Comment: @adeno, I'm not sure about `"set-Cookie" : "some=data; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT"`, but `req.headers.cookie` gets set If you comment out the redirect, and run the server twice.

Comment: Are you redirecting to a different domain?  Cookies expire when the session ends by default, so if you redirect to another domain you're going to lose the cookie unless you set the expiration to a later date.

Comment: @maembe No, Ia m redirecting back to the same server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get and Set a Single Cookie with Node.js HTTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double status setting (200 and 301, I'm not sure if it is possible) You can render html page with META tag `HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"` instead of redirectig status, e.g.

```
var jsrender = require('node-jsrender');

(..)

res.writeHead(200, {'Set-Cookie': cookie, 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

// 301 redirection replaced by rendering html template with redirection inside

var tmpl = jsrender.loadFileSync('#redirectTemplate', 'templates/redirect.html')

res.end( tmpl.render() );
```

And `redirect.html` looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1;URL=/redirect-url">
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

To redirect a client after setting a cookie without `Express`, just pass the URL you want to redirect to, to `res.address`.

```
var url = "https://someurl.com";    

res.address(url);

res.end();
```

Comment: `res.address` is not a function in node, unless I'm missing something.