# accessing cookies in aws lambda; SAM template and sam local start-api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I want to be able to read a cookie from my browser request in an aws lambda. I have found this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simply-serverless-using-aws-lambda-to-expose-custom-cookies-with-api-gateway/ which seems to work.

However, this is not very useful in development in a aws-sam-cli application. I'm not sure how I would set this up using the SAM template format using a local server that is started with `sam local start-api`.

I've read through the template documentation, however I haven't found it yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using AWS Gateway API, can I access the cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572887/using-aws-gateway-api-can-i-access-the-cookies) AWS SAM uses API Gateway Proxy integration which is discussed in the linked question.

Comment: That would require setup on through the console in aws services. I don't know how that would translate into a sam template  to be parsed by `sam local start-api`. I'll update the question to be more specific.

Comment: I guess that you are referring to the [SAM quick start](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-quick-start.html)? You can still use the aws-sam-cli for development (try logging the event on the first line of your event handler in the `hello-world/app.js` file to see the request headers). That said, browsers typically don't store cookies from localhost unless you do some additional configuration.