# Pass session cookie to AWS Lambda using Amazon Gateway HTTP API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-gateway

I have an Amazon Gateway HTTP API with AWS Lambda integration, which I created with these AWS CLI commands:

```
aws apigatewayv2 create-api --name test --protocol-type HTTP --target arn:aws:lambda:...

aws apigatewayv2 get-integrations --api-id {API_ID}

aws lambda add-permission \
 --statement-id api-invoke-lambda \
 --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
 --function-name "arn:aws:lambda:..." \
 --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com \
 --source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:..."

aws apigatewayv2 update-api --api-id {API_ID} --cors-configuration AllowCredentials=true,AllowOrigins="https://..."
```

I call the lambda with AJAX and I would like to pass the session cookie in the request. Is this possible?

The AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://{API_ID}.execute-api.....amazonaws.com/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { },
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572887/using-aws-gateway-api-can-i-access-the-cookies

Comment: @MarkB I know this entry, but it is for REST API. I don't know how to use it for HTTP API. It didn't solve my problem

Comment: I don't think it matters if it is REST or HTTP API, it matters more that it is a Lambda proxy API integration, which is true in both cases. That means the cookie headers should already be there in the `event` object in your Lambda function. Are you printing/logging the `event` object to see if it is already in there?

Comment: Yes, it is not. I believe that CORS  and ajax configuration are the key to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the AJAX call is already including the cookie in the HTTP request headers, but you can verify if that is the case simply by viewing the request headers in your browser's developer tools network tab.

Comment: According to the dev tools of Firefox, request cookies is empty.

Comment: I just realized you're posting to a `https://{API_ID}.execute-api.....amazonaws.com/` URL, instead of your own custom URL. The browser will never send the cookie to that URL unless you are also setting the session cookie from another API Gateway URL. If you are setting the session cookie from another domain name, the browser will never pass it to that API Gateway URL.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, the solution was to use a custom URL. If you write your last comment as an answer, I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting to an `https://{API_ID}.execute-api.....amazonaws.com/` URL, instead of your own custom URL. The browser will never send the cookie to that URL unless you are also setting the session cookie from another API Gateway URL. If you are setting the session cookie from another domain name, the browser will never pass it to that API Gateway URL.