# ExpressJS Cookie-Parser not persisting between different HTTP calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies

I am using [Cookie - Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) with express.js. In my express config file I have `app.use(cookieParser())` and in my main (app.js) for the server I set the cookie whenever there is a POST request to `/signIn` and username and password are both equal.

```
app.post("/signIn",(req,res)=>{
    log(`Checking .....`);
    const req_data=req.body;
    log(req.body);
    if(req.body.user===req.body.password) {
        res.cookie.level="recruiter";//I even tried doing with res.cookie("level","recruiter")
        res.send({redirect:true,redirect_url:"\\"+res.cookie.level})
    } else {
        log(`Fishy..!`);
        res.send({"authenticated":false});
    }
});
```

Now when the client receives this as a part of the Fetch API response it extracts the `redirect_url` part of the JSON and do something like below:

```
fetch("/signIn",{
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(json)
})
.then((res)=>{
    log(res);
    return res.json();
})
.then((res)=>{
    if(res["authenticated"] == false) {
        $("#credential_alert").style="display:block;";
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#credential_alert").style="display:none;";
        },1000);
        $("#user").value="";
        $("#password").value="";
    } else if(res["redirect"]===true && res["redirect_url"]) {
        window.location.href=res["redirect_url"];
    }
})
```

Now real issue is when in another route I am trying to access a HTTP cookie previously set in the `/signIn` route using below code..

```
app.get("/recruiter",(req,res)=>{
    log(req.cookies.level);//Coming out as undefined
    res.render("recruiter.ejs");
});
```

As you can see, `level` from `res.cookies` is coming out as undefined I don't know why.

**Answer**
Got the answer, actually `fetch` API does not send any credentials by default with it's request so we have to set `credentials:true` to send credentials along with fetch api's call.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server) .

Answer (score 0):

Hi Actually You're setting cookie only for that request means(by defualt httpOnly :true)
So you've to set cookie like this
res.cookie("level","recruiter",{httpOnly:false,maxAge:/optional/})