# Get specific cookie from request headers (express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, request

I came across an issue today with express, assume we set several cookies, when I use `request.headers` only one cookie is returned:

```
cookie: 'userSession=123'
```

for example, not only can't I use `request.headers.cookie` as it is unreliable (users can have several cookies set), but I can't parse it into a JSON object (this is invalid json) nor can I select this cookie specifically, which leads to a subquestion, is this how we get cookies from express response, through headers?

Comment: This will work with multiple cookies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3409200/2797034 though if you are only receiving one cookie, its likely because that is all that is sent in the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `cookieParser()` from `$ npm install cookie-parser`