# Response cookie not being sent in Fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, fetch

I'm currently sending a cookie back from my Node server like this:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [`session=${sessionCookie}; HttpOnly; Secure`]);
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'}));
```

When I go to Chrome, I can see in the Network call that the session cookie is received. It's not making its way over to the Application tab.

I'm then going to make my call using Fetch (have tried both 'include' and 'same-origin' but cannot find the cookie in the Fetch request.

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/test`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
```

Is there anything wrong with this setup that may be causing the cookie to not make its way into the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In options object you need to pass **same-origin** in mode and **include** in credentials.

Hope this link will help you to solve the issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42735086/6712441

Thanks

Comment: Awesome! That worked for sending the current cookies, but still didn't send the "session" cookie. Any idea why that specific cookie has not been sent and handled correctly?

Comment: Send cookie like this `res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, {httpOnly: true, secure: true});`

Comment: I think that's a function of Express, res.cookie is not a function for me.

Comment: If you are not using express, you can try with **res.writeHead()** function. This [https://stackoverflow.com/a/3409200/6712441] should help you.