# getCookie("cookiename") is showing value with % how to get the value without it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm setting a cookie in my node server code using the following:

```
let userid = db._id  //console.log shows the id as :  abc123456789d
res.cookie("uid", userid , { sameSite: "none", secure: true })
```

Is this the right way or am I doing anything wrong?

in my front application I use js to get the cookie using the following code :

```
let x =  document.cookie
  let cookie = getCookie("uid")
  console.log("cookies value:",cookie)
```

the console log shows the cookie value as this :

```
j%3A%abc123456789d%22
```

I tried to set the cookie with JSON.stringify() and the front is showing the cookie value as this:

```
%3A%abc123456789d%22
```

My question is why I don't get the value without the % value %22 and how to correct this output so I get the value of the id as id that I get from the db which should be

```
abc123456789d
```

Note that the id I mentioned here is just for demonstration purpose only and doesn't exist in real life. The id I get back from my db is 48 character with just letters and numbers (no special character, something like 666de2f0600eda239ae05d88)

It's my first time I try to get a cookie value using js so it seems that I'm missing something and after reading online, I can't figure out why this % %22 surround my id. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: unescape? anyway `and doesn't exist in real life` is obvous, since a `j` disappeared, and the unescaped value of what you presented would be `:«c123456789d"` including that quote ... so - yeah, `unescape` is what you need to use

Comment: oh, and if your cookie value has `%22` in it, it's because the value is being set with the `"` (that's what a %22 is) as part of the value - I'd check the code that sets the cookie for obvious errors

Comment: What's the code for `getCookie`?

Comment: msbit : it is %3A%abc123456789d%22

Comment: csx.cc suggested decodeURIComponent() and I added split and now I get "abc123456789d"     -- I just need to get rid of " " and I will have the value of the id. How to get rid of "" around the id value? Any suggestion?

Comment: No, I meant what's the code for the `getCookie` function. `j%3A%abc123456789d%22` is the value that this function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is missing URI decode/encode

> The decodeURIComponent() function decodes a Uniform Resource
> Identifier (URI) component previously created by encodeURIComponent or
> by a similar routine.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: Thank you. it gave me the output without the % %22 so I have the output as "abc123456789d" how to get rid of the "  " around the value? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this :

```
 let x =  document.cookie
 let decodit = decodeURIComponent(x).split(":").toString()
  let sliceit = decodit.slice(7, 31)
```

Thanks csx.cc ...your answer led me in the right direction.

## **I'm using express and cookie parser. After reading about how they encode the cookie, I found an answer on stackoverflow.com and here is the answer (I upvoted the answer and anyone reading this should do the same. Link to the answer at the end)**

Note on external libraries:
If you decide to use the express, cookie-parser, or cookie, note they have defaults that are non-standard. Cookies parsed are always URI Decoded (percent-decoded). That means if you use a name or value that has any of the following characters: !#$%&'()*+/:<=>?@[]^`{|} they will be handled differently with those libraries. If you're setting cookies, they are encoded with %{HEX}. And if you're reading a cookie you have to decode them.

For example, while email=name@domain.com is a valid cookie, these libraries will encode it as email=name%40domain.com. Decoding can exhibit issues if you are using the % in your cookie. It'll get mangled. For example, your cookie that was: secretagentlevel=50%007and50%006 becomes secretagentlevel=507and506. That's an edge case, but something to note if switching libraries.

Also, on these libraries, cookies are set with a default path=/ which means they are sent on every url request to the host.

If you want to encode or decode these values yourself, you can use encodeURIComponent or decodeURIComponent, respectively.

## Answer by ShortFuse:
[Get and Set a Single Cookie with Node.js HTTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server)