# How to get cookie in php send from Node.js application

Tags: php, node.js

How to get cookie in php send from Node.js application? I am not fimiliar to php. How to get this cookie creted in nodejs in php?

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 3000
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
        res.setHeader("Set-Cookie","type-test");
        res.setHeader("Year",new Date().getFullYear);
      res.send('Hello World!')
    })
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example -**

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "type-test";

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
  echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
  echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
  echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello @AmmarAslam i have no idea about php i used your code and i got an error :
Warning: Undefined variable $cookie_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 2

Warning: Undefined variable $cookie_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 3
Cookie named '' is not set!

Comment: $cookie_name is a variable, that will store the name of the cookie, let me modify the example

Comment: Your code removed err but i am not getting the value printed. This is Actual Result i am getting :  Cookie 'type-test is set!
Value is:

Comment: res.setHeader("Set-Cookie","type-test=whatever_value");

Comment: Still Value is coming empty in Developers tool under Request Header : I am getting Cookie: type-test; type-test=whatever_value

Comment: The problem is definitely in the cookie set in your node code, the cookie value you're setting in node probably is empty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server