# Guidance With This Javascript Syntax: `name = name?.trim();`

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I found a code snippet on this site for parsing cookies. Credit to Pomax for posting it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393854/get-and-set-a-single-cookie-with-node-js-http-server).
There is some syntax in the code that I don't understand:

```
function parseCookies (headers) {
const list = {};

const { Cookie } = headers;
if (!Cookie) return list;

Cookie.split(`;`).forEach((cookie) => {
    let [ name, ...rest] = cookie.split(`=`);
    name = name?.trim(); //What is this doing?
    if (!name) return;
    const value = rest.join(`=`).trim();
    if (!value) return;
    list[name] = decodeURIComponent(value);
});

return list;
```

};

The syntax I don't understand is here:

```
name = name?.trim();
```

Can someone help me understand what the `?` is doing, and possibly point me to where it's documented in the MDN Web Docs?
Thank you!

Comment: basically it lets you try and access something that might not exist without checking that it exists first. you use it when the attribute/method you're accessing is possibly undefined or null. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: aside - google is bad at punctuation unless you write out the symbols in english - try `javascript question mark dot`i get https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining #1, ymmv